# std::ifstream::open() fails in Windows 10 Universal apps

Tags: c++, visual-c++, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a **Windows 10 Universal C++** project and I'm trying to open a binary file in read-mode using `std::ifstream`.

This is my code:

```
std::ifstream imgFile("C:\\Users\\GuiTeK\\Desktop\\picture.bmp", std::ios::binary);

if (imgFile.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
}

else
{
    int error = errno;
    std::cerr << "KO: " << error << std::endl;
}
```

Problem is that it keeps failing with **error 13**, which means "*The data is invalid*" (C.F. [System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)).

However, the exact same code **works fine** in a Win32 Console Application C++ project.

What's wrong?

Comment: What permissions does your application's manifest request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UWP apps do not have permission to access all files on the device. By default, apps can access certain file system locations such as application install directory or application data locations. For more info, please see [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

`"C:\Users\GuiTeK\Desktop\picture.bmp"` is a location that you app can't directly access. In UWP, we will need a [File​Open​Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker) to access such a file. One important rule here is that [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).

For more info about how to handle files in UWP, please see [Files, folders, and libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/) and also [File access sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess), [File picker sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FilePicker) on GitHub.